# OnTouchEvent every swipe another action

Tags: java, android

I have this code:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            x1 = event.getX();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            x2 = event.getX();
            float deltaX = x2 - x1;

            if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE) {
                if (x2 > x1) {
                 //from right to left

            } else {

                    // from left to right
                }
            }
            break;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

I want to remake this code so that when I first swipe it make some action when I second swipe it make another action and when I third swipe it make again another action...

Can any help to me? 
Thank for every answer

Comment: Do you mean each swipe is happening separately? As in your finger touches the phone, swipes, lifts up, then the second swipe begins? Or do you mean that the second and third swipes begin while the first is still occurring, i.e. multitouch?

Comment: Yes each swipe separately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a class variable to store how many times a swipe has occurred, and act accordingly.

```
private int swipeCounter = 0;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            x1 = event.getX();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            x2 = event.getX();
            float deltaX = x2 - x1;

            boolean left = Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE;

            swipeCounter++;

            switch(swipeCounter) {
                case 1:
                    ...
                    break;
                case 2:
                    ...
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

I left your other logic alone, but there are a couple things I would recommend changing. First, if the swipe distance is not greater than `MIN_DISTANCE` it will always register as a right swipe. You may want to change that. Also, you may want to do this check within an `ACTION_MOVE` event, so that your actions always occur after a user swipes a certain distance, instead of when they lift their finger. (So- calculate the delta during every move, if it is greater than `MIN_DISTANCE` determine if it was left or right and increment `swipeCounter`.)

Comment: I need swipe from left to right and conversely? can you please add this code?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check that you are dealing with the right swipe, which means you don't check for the indexes of the presses, you can use : { motionEvent.getX(pointerIndex) }, second, you need to check if the user swipe to one direction and then swipe to the other direction, if it means anything at all, third you don't check what happens if it the touch event is canceled, and to end this comment do you really want to pass the touch event to the parent  ?

As for the solution, use getActionIndex, save the the x's in arraylist or hashmap so you'll have some sort of easy access back to the first x according to the index of the action, that way you can handle many swipes as the screen can support, and it will be very robust, don't forget to check for action_canceled, so if it canceled remove the x from the array, I would use hashmap, it might be expensive but will work the fastest.